# Creating a unique sequence of dates

Tags: r, date, sequence

Let's say that I want to generate a data frame which contains a column with 
is structured in the following format.

```
2011-08-01
2011-08-02
2011-08-03
2011-08-04
...
```

I want to know if it's possible to generate this data with the `seq()` command.

Something like the following: (obviously doesn't work)

```
seq(2011-08-01:2011-08-31)
```

Would I instead have to use toDate and regex to generate this date in this
specific format.

Comment: Try reading all the way down to the bottom of `?seq`.

Comment: Note that if the purpose of this is to create a time series with those dates then you can avoid creating this sequence explicitly by creating a zooreg object.  This example creates a `"zooreg"` class time series whose values are 1, 2, ..., 10 for 10 consecutive dates starting at 2011-08-01:  `library(zoo); z <- zooreg(1:10, as.Date("2011-08-01"))` .

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As I noted in my comment, `seq` has method for dates, `seq.Date`:

```
seq(as.Date('2011-01-01'),as.Date('2011-01-31'),by = 1)
 [1] "2011-01-01" "2011-01-02" "2011-01-03" "2011-01-04" "2011-01-05" "2011-01-06" "2011-01-07" "2011-01-08"
 [9] "2011-01-09" "2011-01-10" "2011-01-11" "2011-01-12" "2011-01-13" "2011-01-14" "2011-01-15" "2011-01-16"
[17] "2011-01-17" "2011-01-18" "2011-01-19" "2011-01-20" "2011-01-21" "2011-01-22" "2011-01-23" "2011-01-24"
[25] "2011-01-25" "2011-01-26" "2011-01-27" "2011-01-28" "2011-01-29" "2011-01-30" "2011-01-31"
```

Comment: a bit more flexible way is seq(as.Date('2011-01-01'),as.Date('2011-01-31'),by = 'day') and one can generate seq by month or by year by using by = 'month' or any other interval

Answer (score 12):

I have made the same mistake with seq() attempting to make a numeric sequence. Don't use the ":" operator between arguments, and they will need to be dates if you want to make a date sequence. Another way is to take one date and add a numeric sequence starting with 0:

```
> as.Date("2000-01-01") + 0:10
 [1] "2000-01-01" "2000-01-02" "2000-01-03" "2000-01-04" "2000-01-05" "2000-01-06"
 [7] "2000-01-07" "2000-01-08" "2000-01-09" "2000-01-10" "2000-01-11"
```

Answer (score 9):

You could try `timeBasedSeq` in the xts package.  Notice the argument is a string and the use of the double-colon.

```
timeBasedSeq("2011-08-01::2011-08-31")
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me! I know it's similar to the most upvoted answer, but that fact that i can specify "1 month" in text is amazing!

```
seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"),as.Date("2019-12-01"), by = "1 month")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to generate a seq by min, and it was no easy, but i found [seq.POSIXt](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.POSIXt.html) in base. In your case, you want a seq of daily data from 2011-08-01 to 2011-08-31. So i suggest you

```
days <- seq(ISOdate(2011,8,1), by = "day", length.out = 31)
class(days)
"POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clock`'s [`date_build`](https://clock.r-lib.org/reference/date_build.html?q=date_build#null), which comes with nice functionalities and useful error message:

```r
library(clock)
date_build(2011, 8, 1:31)
```