# How can I create a date sequence in Stata?

Tags: date, stata

I wish to create a date sequence in Stata. A search on this forum and others did not yield any helpful code for Stata. There are many answers for R as shown for example on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536306/creating-a-unique-sequence-of-dates) link. I want to create a sequence from January 1, 2000 to December 31, 2010. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dates can be tricky in any software. In Stata, like any other software, there really is no substitute for reading the documentation carefully. `help dates and times` answers most questions. A quirk that may trap the unwary is that `date()` in Stata is a function for creating **daily** date variables, and no other kind. It is best, from Stata 13 on, for new users to use the synonymous function `daily()` when they seek daily dates. 
That said, another function is more convenient here for creating date sequences, `mdy()`.

Here is an example:

```
clear 
di mdy(1,1,2000)
di mdy(12,31,2010)
di mdy(12,31,2010) - mdy(1,1,2000)
set obs 4018
gen mydate = mdy(12,31,1999) + _n
format mydate %td
list in 1
list in L
```

Notes:

1. `mdy()` creates daily date variables from arguments indicating month, day and year.
2. `_n` is observation number, 1 up.
3. So you need to work out the starting date and the number of observations desired and then it's just a case of adding the required constant to `_n`.
4. Stata works with daily date origin 1 January 1960, but this solution does not depend on your knowing that.

P.S. In an answer now deleted, @Caty seems to be asking for a sequence of monthly dates. Here is an edited version:

> When I try that, my dates look like this 01jan2000, 02jan2000. But
>   they should be monthly: 01jan2000, 01feb2000.

If you have monthly data, there is precisely no need for, and precisely no advantages in, working with daily dates that are the first of each month, at least as far as Stata is concerned. In fact, by creating such a sequence you create a sequence with gaps variously 27, 28, 29 and 30 days long, so not even a sequence that is regularly spaced. Those gaps will make many analyses in Stata awkward and some impossible. Similar comments apply to quarters. (If you have weeks, daily dates 7 days apart are the best framework, which is another story.)

```
clear 
di ym(2000, 1)
di ym(2010, 12)
di ym(2010, 1) - ym(2000,1)
set obs 121 
gen mydate = ym(1999, 12) + _n
format mydate %tm 
l in 1
l in L
```

Notes:

1. `ym()` creates monthly date variables from arguments indicating year and month.
2. `_n` is observation number, 1 up.
3. So you need to work out the starting date and the number of observations desired and then it's just a case of adding the required constant to `_n`.
4. Stata works with monthly date origin January 1960, but this solution does not depend on your knowing that.

EDIT End-of-month daily sequences are easy with a trick that you may kick yourself for not seeing immediately. Suppose we want the ends of January 2015 to December 2016. Then the end of each month is just one day before the beginning of the next month. There is no need to worry about months of differing lengths or about leap years. Stata knows the details of the calendar, so you don't have to tell it what they are.

```
. clear

. set obs 24 
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 24

. gen mdate = ym(2015, 1) + _n 

. gen ddate = dofm(mdate) - 1 

. format %td ddate

. format %tm mdate 

. list 

     +---------------------+
     |   mdate       ddate |
     |---------------------|
  1. |  2015m2   31jan2015 |
  2. |  2015m3   28feb2015 |
  3. |  2015m4   31mar2015 |
  4. |  2015m5   30apr2015 |
  5. |  2015m6   31may2015 |
     |---------------------|
  6. |  2015m7   30jun2015 |
  7. |  2015m8   31jul2015 |
  8. |  2015m9   31aug2015 |
  9. | 2015m10   30sep2015 |
 10. | 2015m11   31oct2015 |
     |---------------------|
 11. | 2015m12   30nov2015 |
 12. |  2016m1   31dec2015 |
 13. |  2016m2   31jan2016 |
 14. |  2016m3   29feb2016 |
 15. |  2016m4   31mar2016 |
     |---------------------|
 16. |  2016m5   30apr2016 |
 17. |  2016m6   31may2016 |
 18. |  2016m7   30jun2016 |
 19. |  2016m8   31jul2016 |
 20. |  2016m9   31aug2016 |
     |---------------------|
 21. | 2016m10   30sep2016 |
 22. | 2016m11   31oct2016 |
 23. | 2016m12   30nov2016 |
 24. |  2017m1   31dec2016 |
     +---------------------+
```

Comment: This is a great answer and helped me out a lot! For the sake of learning: What does `l in 1` and `l in L ` do?

Comment: `l` is a minimal abbreviation for `list` and then `in 1` and `in L` mean in the first and last observations. `in l` is also allowed.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me quite a bit!

Comment: I wonder if it is also possible to create a sequence of consecutive of end month dates (that is 31.01.2015 - 28.02.2016 - 31.03.2016 and so on)?

Comment: Naturally; the end of each month is just one day before the beginning of the next month! I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, Nick! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Stata handles dates as integers with a corresponding format, so it boils down to figuring out which integers you need, generating the sequence and giving the appropriate format. One way is:

```
clear all
set more off

// get corresponding integers
local start = date("2000/01/01", "YMD")
local end = date("2010/12/31", "YMD")
local ob = `end' - `start' + 1

// generate variable
set obs `ob'
egen date = seq(), from(`start') to(`end')
format %td date

list
```

See `help datetime` and [[U] 24 Working with dates and times](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/u24.pdf).