# Convert Interval vector to a vector of dates

Tags: r, intervals

I'm using **fmdates** package in R and got an Interval vector as below:

```
generate_schedule(effective_date, termination_date, tenor, calendar,bdc, stub, eom_rule=FALSE)
```

> [1] 2017-01-03 UTC--2018-02-09 UTC 2018-02-09 UTC--2019-02-11 UTC

Is there any function that convert this Interval vector to a vector of dates? For example, I expect a result as **2017-01-03 2018-02-09 2019-02-11** in this case.

Comment: Which language are you using there?

Comment: Oh sorry I'm using R. Just edited my post.

Comment: You can split it on `--` and create the sequence between the two dates. See [here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536306/creating-a-unique-sequence-of-dates)