# How to repeat sequence of days 1:7 based on continuous days to correspond with weeks

Tags: r, rep

I want to add a column of days each week to my dataset which contains continuous days and continuous weeks already for a large dataset

I've tried to use the floor function and the rep function already

*Edit* I'm attempting to automate the final output mydata$day_of_week

```
time_in_hrs<-c(0,2,12,24,25,29,30,32,38,43,57,82,93,105,199,205,245,263)
mydata<-as.data.frame(time_in_hrs)
mydata$time_in_days<-floor(mydata$time_in_hrs/24)+1
mydata$time_in_weeks<-floor(mydata$time_in_days/8)+1
mydata$day_of_week<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,2,2,4,4)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536306/creating-a-unique-sequence-of-dates

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I think the expected outcome is currently simulated by the `mydata$day_of_week` and Marcosullivan is looking to automate this.

Comment: @bbiasi that thread question does not relate to my question

Comment: @RonakShah I've edited my post to explain this better, apologies

Comment: @Sven this is correct

Comment: Could you show your original dataset and dataset you want as output? It will become clearer to understand what your goal is.

Comment: Hi Marcosullivan, in that case my answer below should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to automate the column `mydata$day_of_week` that you're now doing manually, you can do this as follows:

```
mydata$day_of_week_auto <- mydata$time_in_days - (mydata$time_in_weeks - 1) * 7
```

Answer (score 0):

with the rep-command you can try the following:

```
mydata$days <- rep(c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", Thursday", 
"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"), times = 5)

mydata$days <- rep(1:7, times = 5)
```

Hope this might help you.

Best, Veronika

Comment: Hi @veronika unfortunately, this doesn't work as it doesn't recognise the variation in the time/day columns